# Return object from arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to output object from arrow function (in a short form), so full code is:

```
somemethod(function(item) {
   return {id: item.id};
})
```

with arrow functions it's:

```
somemethod((item) => {
   return {id: item.id};
})
```

and now short form should be something like:

```
somemethod(item = > {id: item.id} )
```

that does not work, as well as this one:

```
somemethod(item = > {{id: item.id}} )
```

only one solution I found for now is to use create Object notation:

```
somemethod(item = > new Object({id: item.id}) )
```

is there another way?

Comment: `somemethod(({id}) => ({id}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
somemethod(item => ({ id: item.id }))
```

Test:

```
> a = item => ({id: item.id})
< function item => ({id: item.id})
> a({ id: 5, name: 7 });
< Object {id: 5}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Objects you have wrap your object using parentheses or else it doesn't work

This is because the code inside braces ({}) is parsed as a sequence of statements

Try as below

```
var func = () => ({ foo: 1 });
```

refer : [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)