# What does the JavaScript syntax foo: mean?

Tags: javascript

what does the following code meaning? (it is not json - it is code which does not generate error by js interpreter)

```
foo: 5
```

The reason for the question is as follows. In the arrow function examples there is one that shows the confusion between json and code block syntax:

```
var func = () => { foo: 1 };
```

The func() returns undefined and the above code does not fail. I tried to put just the foo: 5 code as the only code in a js module - and it works... I do not know about a ':' operator neither about labels in js.

Comment: It's a label. That is all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return object from arrow function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551000/return-object-from-arrow-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a JavaScript label: [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

> You can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.
>
> Note that JavaScript has NO goto statement, you can only use labels with break or continue.

**Example usage (from MDN)**

```
var itemsPassed = 0;
var i, j;

top:
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  for (j = 0; j < tests.length; j++) {
    if (!tests[j].pass(items[i])) {
      continue top;
    }
  }

  itemsPassed++;
}
```

Comment: As per quoted documentation, JS label is relevant for loop only. In my example there is no loop following the label. But it's still legal code.

Comment: @dzilbers if you keep reading the documentation, it states that you can use blocks (section: "Using a labeled block with break") and even functions. The Javascript parser will expect an expression to follow the `label`. Unless you're in strict mode, in which case it will limit what can follow.

Comment: I have looked now into MDN and into ECMA specs about labelled statement. It is strange (why labels that are not adjacent to a loop or to a block are acceptable at all if there is no any reason for their usage?) but it is true...