# What does the symbol ":" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I found this code in Ionic framework:

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }
```

what does that `:` in `alertCtrl: AlertController` means?

Comment: could this be typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) which has a link to a question reguarding the specific symbol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655737/javascript-strange-syntax-that-works-but-how

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript

Comment: The code you posted is not JS, possibly be TypeScript

Comment: It's a TypeScript type annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The : in typescript means type assignment/annotation...

`alertCtrl: AlertController` means declare `alertCtrl` as `AlertController`, which will only accept `Objects` of `AlertController` type.

`count:number`  means declare count as number, which will only accept `number`.

`name:string` means declare name as string, which will only accept a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is written in TypeScript, which is a language that is compiled to JavaScript.


The `:` symbol is used to specify typing. It can come after a variable declaration to specify its type, after a function's parameter or after the function's heading to specify it's return type (which can be void).


Examples:

```
let a: number = 8;
function (b: number): number { return b; }
```