# Some strange syntax issues in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using greeting variable inside function

```
function greet3() {
    greeting : 'HELLO GREET 3';
    this.greet = function () {
        console.log(greeting);
    };
}
```

this syntax does not give any error and also I am not able to fetch "greeting" in any case .I want to know what is happening here?

Comment: Declare/assign variables with `=`, not with `:`. (Also, preferably use a keyword like `const` first to avoid implicitly making it global.)

Comment: I know but I want to know that what happens when I do that , is js engine ignores this line completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript strange syntax that works - but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655737/javascript-strange-syntax-that-works-but-how)

Comment: It's a label. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212), [MDN: Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Comment: You can also use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) which yields _“Label 'greeting' on HELLO GREET 3 statement.”_.

Comment: simple solution ... don't use *strange syntax* :p

Answer (score 1):

- first you have to use '=' instead of ':' for assign
- second you must have to use this keyword for referring variable which allow to use variable in local scope or use var
  here is a code

  ```
  function greet3() {
      this.greeting = 'HELLO GREET 3';
      this.greet = function () {
          console.log(this.greeting);
      };
  }

  var g =  new greet3();
   g.greet();
  ```

Comment: thanks manan5439 for your answer  , but I was looking if I do that then what is actually happening .

Comment: Ok maybe you got your ans :-)