# What is the syntax {object}[index] called?

Tags: javascript, syntax

In React, I use this kind of syntax often for conditional rendering:

```
const exampleState = 1;

const retval = {
    0: "Value for state 0",
    1: "Value for state 1",
    2: "Value for state 2",
}[exampleState]

// this returns "Value for state 1"
```

What is this syntax called?

Edit: added `const retval` to make it actually valid code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: In this case "invalid". Although, I assume you mean [bracket syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets). It's a type or property access.

Comment: There is nothing special about this syntax. You have just declared an object but it is a temporary as you didn’t assign it to a variable. You then just get the property with key 1 of the temporary object.

Comment: @VLAZ fixed the code. Bracket syntax is it, I was just overthinking it and trying to find a name for a specific shorthand when it's just an object declared and accessed in the same line as Paul Rooney says above. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @PaulRooney super simple once you point it out, I was just overthinking it before, thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{ }` block defines an object. The `[]` part is a bracket notation of a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: "*The { } block defines an object*" only in this case, it defines a block with labels.

Comment: @Teemu If one uses *literally* the same code as OP shows, then `{ }` does *not* define an object but a code block. A `{` in the beginning of the line will not interpreted as an object literal syntax. Since this will be parsed as a code block, the `0:` should be [a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655737/what-does-the-javascript-syntax-foo-mean). However, a label cannot start with a number, therefore the code in the OP will throw a syntax error. Nothing to do with object's keys, as there *aren't* any objects or keys defined.

Comment: This is what I needed, somehow I didn't realize that it was this simple and I was looking for some short of shorthand to call it...thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
{
    0: "Value for state 0",
    1: "Value for state 1",
    2: "Value for state 2",
}
```

is a ***key: value* pair** object.

So your code returns the value of key `0` from this object.