# What does the statement a:bc = 9 will do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have written a:bc = 9 in javascript.

when i `console.log(bc) its printing 9

but when I `console.log(a)` it gives "a" is not defined.

could anyone help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't reproduce the described behavior. Could you fix it?

Comment: `console.log(a:cv)` is invalid syntax; `a:bc = 9` is just a label [What does the JavaScript syntax foo: mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39655737)

Comment: hi, made changes could you look at it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the JavaScript syntax foo: mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655737/what-does-the-javascript-syntax-foo-mean)

Comment: no buddy if "a" is the label and when I am logging it, it should not throw any error, right?

Comment: You cannot log a label. It *will* throw an error if you try to log it. However, your description does not make sense, since `console.log(a:bc)` would *also* throw an error. It cannot log anything. Without a [mcve] it seems you're not showing real code.

Comment: actually am working with REPL, hence the confusion, but got it, thanks for the explanation  :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a:bc = 9
```

As per ECMAScript only a:bc = 9 its just a **label** and the last **bc** gets assigned to 9 and **a** will not have any effects.

```
console.log(bc); // 9 only this statement will work
```