# why this syntax not producing Error {age:15}toString() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Try this syntax in console

```
 {age:15}toString()  
 '[object Undefined]' // this is the return
```

why this happens it looks syntactically wrong so I'm not sure how the interpreter parse it ?

the object `{age:15}` looks like completely ignored ? is that true ?

if not ignored dose it mean it garbage as soon as it created I'm just thinking but not sure

Comment: ofc it will throw an error unless u meant to type `{age:15}.toString()`

Comment: @ChrisG doesn't. It's syntactically correct.

Comment: `toString()` on its own gets you the exact same result.

Comment: @CBroe I know but I didn't know the first part how it parsed

Comment: Interesting. Looks like `{ age: 15 }` and `toString()` are evaluated as two separate statements.

Comment: I guess the curly brackets serve as instruction separator here. You could make that `{age:15};toString()` to make it more obvious, but the result is the same.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'toString'`

Comment: Wait so `age:15;toString()` would also work. Interesting.

Comment: `{...}` is a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), `age:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and `15` is just a stand-alone number literal. It's syntactically correct, but doesn't make much sense logically.

Comment: @ChrisG your interpreter is broken. The code is valid.

Comment: @Reyno Yeah. `age:15` is just a labelled statement that doesn't do anything. If you wrap it in a block it still doesn't do anything. No matter how much it's changed, while it's inconsequential to the code, it won't change things. Which I guess is a bit of a tautology.

Comment: @VLAZ I figured it was a block followed by a `toSring()` call but I forgot about the label statement since it is rarely used, hence it confused me. You'll learn something everyday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{age:15}`:

1. Is [a block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). It is not an object. For more information see [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the) and in particular the explanations for `{} + []` and `{} + {}` that deal with the same block behaviour.
2. It contains [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) with identifier `age` which is then followed by the expression-statement `15`. For more see [What does the JavaScript syntax foo: mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655737/what-does-the-javascript-syntax-foo-mean)
3. It is irrelevant to the rest of the code.

---

The actual output here is only from `toString()`:

```js
console.log(toString());
```

With that in mind let's examine the output: [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is a method on the object prototype. Thus pretty much all objects have it. Including `window`:

```js
console.log("toString" in window); //true
```

Calling just `toString()` means the method will be picked up from the global object - `window`.

Because [the value of `this` is determined at call time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used) and implicitly there is no object to pick it from:

A normal call would look like `someObject.toString()` which will set the `this` value to `someObject`. It is also equivalent to calling `Object.prototype.toString.call(someObject)` which will explicitly set the value of `this` to `someObject.

However with the entire `toString()` is basically equivalent to `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)` as there is nothing the method is called on.

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined))
```